# Burnination request: [signature] as a synonym of [method-signature] or misused

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) and [method-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-signature) refer to exactly the same up to the point that their descriptions are equal, apart from the disambiguation text on [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature). The problem is, an automated merge isn't possible, because of widespread misuse of the [signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) tag as referring to digital signatures.

Comment: Suggested title options: `A [signature] for burning [signatures]`, `Add your [signature] to the [signatures] supporting burnination?`, or `The [signature] smell of [signatures] burninating`

Answer (score 6):

Well, the tag-wikis might be essentially the same, but usage isn't.

[signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) is used for [method-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-signature) (example: [VS2012 std::function operator bool returns true unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948587/vs2012-stdfunction-operator-bool-returns-true-unexpectedly)) and [digital-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature) (example: [Get a hash (sha) of a sql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211293/get-a-hash-sha-of-a-sql-table)).
There might be a handful others hidden in the edges, but I didn't find them yet.

So, neither synonymizing nor merging is ok, you actually want a [burnination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burnination), a careful [clean-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-up) to properly categorize the posts.

Comment: Possible title for the burnination: Sign up for [signature]'s burnination

Comment: @theB A [signature] for burning [signatures]. (There's a far less famous plural-tag too.)

Comment: Add your [signature] to the [signatures] supporting burnination?

Comment: I read the disclaimer on the [signature] tag, but didn't realize that that disclaimer is there exactly to avoid the misuse of the tag. Okay, I'll edit the title and tags. But I have never participated in a process like that, and I don't know what comes next ;)

Comment: @Axel [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) over on Meta.SE will tell you a lot of what you need to do for burnination. Note that, generally, it should be left to those with >2k rep so that the suggested edit queue is not flooded, and slowly, so the front page is not burdened by an overabundance of `[signature]`-related questions. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: A hash isn't a digital signature, anyway.  (Typically one hashes a document, then digitally signs the hash.)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that post on meta is perfect! If I understand you rightly, are you suggesting me not to elp with the incoming retag process because of my low reputation - to avoid creating review job -, am I wrong?

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena: Well, if you stick to making complete and somewhat bigger edits, your help is very welcome (Restrict yourself to no more than a handful.). The problem is one easily drifts into letting most everything slip by, which is especially apt to irritate people when that happens multiple times in a row. And (presumably) those with full-edit privileges are more likely to know everything that should be done, they also don't go through the review queue. Still, it's *very easy* to irritate those who get all those reactivated posts put on their front-page, even if one does everything right.

Comment: Thank you, yor help is very appreciated